# cron job is running two times instead of one in a particular time?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, cron

I am trying to implement cron job in flask. Code structure is like
  this:

code:

```
    @sched.cron_schedule(second='*/30') 
    def some_decorated_task():
         time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
         print time_now
         print "##########0@@@@@@"
```

output:

```
   2015-03-01 23:53:30.001843
   ##########0@@@@@@
   2015-03-01 23:53:30.002615
   ##########0@@@@@@
```

Why it printing two time instead of one ?

Comment: Are you running this with the development web server or something else?

Comment: I am running this with localhost

Comment: That doesn't really answer Miguel's question. Are you running this with `app.run()`? If so, are you running the application with reloader turned on? If so, that is the source of your problem.

Comment: Yes , I am running this with  app.run(debug=True) along with manager.run()
    ). I did not understand 'the application with reloader turned on'. Could you  please elaborate more on this?

Comment: @BirendraKumar Try setting `debug=False` in your application, I think that'll address your problem. When you run in debug mode there are actually two processes started, a parent process runs the reloader code, and a child process runs the actual application.